# Exception when creating multiple indices with tNeo4jOutput component

Tags: neo4j, indexing, talend

I am trying to add multiple indices on a row on the tNeo4jOutput component, like so:

[image: Creating multiple indices, not working.]

The problem when running the job is that i get error complaining about "Duplicate local variables":

[image: Error message when running the job.]

Full exception:
[image: Full exception, sensitive project names redacted.]

I understand what is happening here, the underlying code is trying to define the same variable twice (once per index entry). But how do I get around this? It seems wierd that you should not be able to add more than one index on creation.
Hopefully i am missing something here that I need to do in Talend but I would also accept a solution that requires to manually changing the generated source, how do I do this then?

Comment: what component are you using? Neo4j-JDBC?

Comment: @PeterNeubauer It's the tNeo4jOutput component. I started a [thread in talendforge](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32297) about the problem. Seems to be a problem in the current version of Talend OS For Big Data, so any idea on a work around would be great!